# TypeScript: No implicit return of `T | undefiend` unions

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

How do I force TypeScript to not implicitly return unions that have `undefined` as part of their type. `T | undefined`

I don't mind implicitly making a function's type a union but I do want to be warned when that union has an undefined as part of it. Something behind a option like noImplicitUndefined

```
thisFunc() { // return string | undefined
    const myDict  = new Map<number, string>();
    return myDict.get(10)
}
//(method) Map<number, string>.get(key: number): string | undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you already tried `--strictNullChecks` compiler switch introduced in TS 2.0?

This would still give you `string|undefined` as a result type but you couldn't use the null value later in your code^.

```
let foo: string | null = null;
foo.toUpperCase() // Compiler Error.
```

if that is now what your looking for something different you might need to fall back (or better say upgrade) to a technique know in functional programming using an Option Type.

```
class Option<T> {
    private value: T;
    constructor(v:T) { this.value = v}
    isSome() {
        return this.value != null && this.value != undefined
    }
    isNone() { return !this.isSome() }
    get() { return this.value }
}


function thisFunc(): Option<string> { 
    const myDict  = new Map<number, string>();
    return new Option(myDict.get(10))
}

let x = thisFunc()

if (x.isSome()) { 
    let z = x.get()
    //do something with z
}
```

Obviously at that level you would only have created a little wrapper around checking for `null || undefined`. This is not very helpful.
So usually you create at least a `map` within the option class.

```
class Option<T> {
    //methods from above
    map<A, B>(f: (A) => B): Option<B>{
        if (this.isSome()) {
            return new Option(f(this.value))
        }
        else {
            return None
        }
    }
}

const None = new Option(null)
```

now the fun really begins as you can easily do

```
thisFunc().map(someFuncWorkOnTheValueWithinOption)
```

also you could define a `match` method which takes an `{some: (x) = y; none: () => z}`.
Or you can get that for free using [ts-option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-option)

Comment: Yes I have nulls checks enabled. Thanks for the write up. Do you think I should file I bug? Seems weird that I still have to worry about undefined.            "alwaysStrict": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch":true,
        "noImplicitThis":true,
        "noImplicitReturns":true,